# My SQL Left join when have some duplicate

Tags: mysql

I try to write code but it work not the same.
I want  `member_preinstall` have 3000.
The result of the code below is 3550.
`memberkohsamui.own` have some duplicate.
How can I make it just joint only one of `memberkohsamui.own` How can  do that

```
SELECT
member_preinstall.own,
member_preinstall.Sname,
memberkohsamui.Sex,
memberkohsamui.Sname,
member_preinstall.Ssurname,
member_preinstall.tambol,
memberkohsamui.dateofbirth
FROM
member_preinstall LEFT JOIN memberkohsamui ON
member_preinstall.own =memberkohsamui.own
```

Comment: what happens if you try a `RIGHT JOIN` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT member_preinstall.own,
    member_preinstall.Sname,
    memberkohsamui.Sex,
    memberkohsamui.Sname,
    member_preinstall.Ssurname,
    member_preinstall.tambol,
    memberkohsamui.dateofbirth
FROM
    member_preinstall LEFT JOIN memberkohsamui ON
    member_preinstall.own =memberkohsamui.own
```